# How do I achieve Pivot in SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to use pivot in SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5, but since the Compact editions don't support pivot how do I do this?

Table: `Donate`

```
    | Name  | Date            | Amount |
    | James | 27/7/2015 20:19 | 500    |
    | Owen  | 27/7/2015 20:20 | 400    |
    | James | 27/7/2015 20:21 | 100    |
```

And so with the following query I can do pivot with no problems

```
select *
from
    (select Name, datename(month, Date) as mname, Amount
     from Donate) as test
pivot(
    sum(Amount)
    for mname in ([July])
) as pvt
```

And get this which is perfect

```
    | Name  | July |
    | James | 600  |
    | Owen  | 400  |
```

But when I use the code is SQL Server compact editions it gives me an error that there is no pivot function. So I researched for a solution and found out that pivot doesn't exist in SQL Server CE.

So anyone know how can I do this in SQL Server Compact Editions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am assuming you need separate columns for separate months.. like if there was a date from January, then you would want to put it in January column. Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Select name,
sum(case datename(month, Date) when 'January' then Amount else 0 end) as Jan,
sum(case datename(month, Date) when  'February' then Amount else 0 end) as Feb,
...
...
From Donate
group by name
```

Comment: Thank you very much hashbrown this works perfectly, I did try to use group by but I didn't try it with cases thats why I didn't came out right. But thank you very much for this awesome code